# How to implement DJ Native Swing JWebBrowser in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, browser, netbeans, djnativeswing

I'm working with netbeans and trying to implement DJ Native Swing JWebBrowser inside a panel but I cant do that.
My Gui is like that:I have buttons on the left which has jpanel for each button(every button i press show me a different jpanel)I want to implement DJ Native Swing JWebBrowser inside one of those panels but cant do that.

when running the DJ Native Swing JWebBrowser as stand alone code,it works fine and open a new jframe and display the browser.

ant help will be appreciated.

Comment: The code gives you 2 panels, so just adjust your buttons..!

Comment: why you can't do that? are you getting any errors ? did you check out the project site for examples ?

Comment: I dont get any error but the gui freezes and cant be closed.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Code:when calendar button is pressed:`card("calendar");` it call for a card named calendar.when the calendar JPanel is shown the code is:`browser br = new browser();
this.add(br);` on the main class:`   NativeInterface.open(); 
         java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                     login log = new login();
                     log.setVisible(true);
                     log.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        }); ` **how do i set the text as code?**

Comment: browser class:    public class browser extends JPanel {   

public  browser() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    webBrowserPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
    final JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
    webBrowser.navigate("https://www.google.com/");
    webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(webBrowserPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}